# Copy and pasting data between cells with Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

[Photo of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pQ1E.png)

Newbie Question

I am guessing this is any easy question for most people here but I can't figure out what I am missing and I've spent quite a while trying to figure it out.

I have a script that is supposed to time stamp different columns. All the if functions work correctly for stamping columns A, E, and F by placing input in columns in B, C, and G respectively.

The one issue I having is getting column E to show input when column d is checked. I've tried a number of different ways(which are commented out in the code.)

I am not sure what I am missing but the difference between the code that is working and the code that isn't is that code that is working uses an offset function to place a date stamp of the current time while the code that isn't working is supposed to copy the data from one row up and two columns over. Essentially this means in an example that when column D10 is checked it should copy the time value in F9 to E10(I have corrected this example since my original post. I was a bit tired when I first wrote it)

Here is the example of my code. I have also attached a picture of the spreadsheet for clarity. I suspect the issue that I using a function wrong but I don't have enough experience to understand why.

```
function onEdit(e){

//CORE VARIABLES
// The columns that trigger datestamps in other columns
var COLUMNB = 2;
var COLUMNC = 3;
var COLUMND = 4;
var COLUMNG = 7;

// Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
// DTL = Date Time Location

//Intiates a series of variables to hold the offset values for datestamping the row entry

//Instiates a variable which controls the offset values for column B name entry 
//The date stamp currently corresponds to column A and is triggered by selecting a client in column B  
var DTLColB = [0,-1];

//Intiates a variable to hold the offset values for datestamping the start time column with the current time
//The date stamp currently corresponds to the time value in column E and the trigger is in column C
var DTLColCCTstart = [0, 2];

//Intiates a variable to hold the offset values for datestamping the start time column with the previous row entry time
//The date stamp currently corresponds to the time value in column E(offset(-1,2))and the trigger is in column D,-,-
//It copies the previous end time into the current start time
var DTLColDLTstart = [0, 1];

//Intiates a variable to hold the offset values for datestamping the current time in the end time col for for a row
//The date stamp currently corresponds to the time value in column F and the trigger is in column G
var DTLColGCTend = [0, -1];

var LastStampCoord = [-1, 2]; 

//Intiates a variable that controls which sheets this function is active on
var SHEETNAME = 'Cont Log'

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.

    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNB) { 
      var dateTimeCellB = selectedCell.offset(DTLColB[0],DTLColB[1]);
      dateTimeCellB.setValue(new Date());
    }

    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNC || selectedCell.getColumn == true ) { 
      var dateTimeCellC = selectedCell.offset(DTLColCCTstart[0],DTLColCCTstart[1]);
      dateTimeCellC.setValue(new Date());
    }

    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMND || selectedCell.getColumn == true) { 
      var dateTimeCellD = selectedCell.offset(DTLColDLTstart[0],DTLColDLTstart[1]);
     // var oldtimevalue = selectedCell.offset(LastStampCoord[0],LastStampCoord[1]);
      // var oldtimevalue = range.selectedCell.offset(LastStampCoord[0],LastStampCoord[1]));
      //var oldtimevalue = selectedCell.offset(LastStampCoord[0],LastStampCoord[1]);
      //var oldtimevalue = selectedCell.getrange(selectedCell.offset(LastStampCoord[0], LastStampCoord[1])).getvalues;
      //var oldtimerecord = sheet.getrange(selectedCell.offset(LastStampCoord[0],LastStampCoord[1])).getvalue();
      //var oldtimevalue = oldtimerecord.getvalue();
      // var LastStampLookup = selectedCell.offset(LastStampCoord[0],LastStampCoord[1]).getvalue();
      // var LastStampTime = LastStampLookup.getvalue()
      // range1.offset(2, 0).setValue("Order complete");
      // dateTimeCellD.offset(LastStampCoord[0], LastStampCoord[1]).setvalue(timelocation);
      //dateTimeCellD.setValue(new oldtimevalue.getvalue());
      dateTimeCellD.setValue(new date());
    }

    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNG || selectedCell.getColumn == true) { 
      var dateTimeCellG = selectedCell.offset(DTLColGCTend[0],DTLColGCTend[1]);
      dateTimeCellG.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/85DwP.png
```

Comment: when column d5 is checked it should copy the time value in C7 to E5? I can not see any time values in your column C.

Comment: I have corrected this since last night. I was a bit more tired than I realized. It should read as follows:

Essentially this means in an example that when column D10 is checked it should copy the time value in F9 to E10

Comment: Put another way if Column D is checked it should copy the date one row up in column F and then paste it in column E in the same row as the original column D.

The purpose of this is to copy the ending time from the previous task into the starting time of the next task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure what I am missing but the difference between the code
>   that is working and the code that isn't

You have a small typing mistake - change

`dateTimeCellD.setValue(new date());`

to

`dateTimeCellD.setValue(new Date());`

However, if your goal is to set the value of `dateTimeCellD` to the one of the cell 1 to the right, one to the top - you can do it with

`dateTimeCellD.setValue(dateTimeCellD.offset(-1,1).getValue());`

See the method descriptions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if( sh.getName()=="Cont Log" ) { 
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    if(e.range.columnStart==2) {e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(ts);}
    if(e.range.columnStart==3) {e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(ts);}
    if(e.range.columnStart==4) {e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(ts);}
    if(e.range.columnStart==7) {e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(ts);}
  }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful and I don't think it answers my issue. This is my fault as I didn't explain things well and had some typos last night(which I've corrected.)

Here is what I am trying to do
 
1.) Create a variable ("var" as an example) 
2.) Retrieve the contents(Let's say the contents F9) of a cell (a date in this example) and place them in Var
3.) Use.setValue() to place the contents of Var(a date) in another cell(E10 as an example)

I think correctly retrieving the date in the cell and placing it in the new cell is the issue as I've been successful with everything else in other code.